# find last cell that has a value (even if it has a formula in it)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula to find the last value of a list:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A55),INDEX(A4:A55,MAX((A4:A55<>"")*(ROW(A4:A55))),A55))
```

However this time it's not working as my cells are not "empty" they have a formula that returns either nothing ("") or a cell:

```
=IF(AND(B50>=$G$4,B50<=$G$5),B50,"")
```

How can I make the index work to find the last cell that actually returns a value?

Comment: Are you looking for the last number or last text or last either?

Answer (score 0):

For the last number,

```
=INDEX(A4:A55, match(1e99, A4:A55))
```

For the last text or number not including zero-length strings,

```
=INDEX(A1:A55, aggregate(14, 6, row(4:55)/sign(len(A4:A55)), 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($A$4:$A$55)>0),$A$4:$A$55)
```